# Difference of means in unequal sample sizes, variances for a boolean data type

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I would like to test the difference in means of two samples in the same population. These samples come from a time series, but because of the way the data is structured, a reliable time series cannot be built.

I thought pooling the data into groups before/after a certain date, and test the difference between these groups.

Each element in this group is a boolean: 1 if condition x, 0 otherwise. As they are pooled into the before/after, the histogram of each looks something like this:

[image]

I thought about Welch's test for unequal samples and variances, but I am unsure of whether this is correct given the constrains.

This is the R command I thought should be ran:

```
t.test(before_year, after_year, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE)
#for completeness, this is the output of the previous test:

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  before_time and after_time
t = 221.01, df = 28117, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6289935 0.6402500
sample estimates:
   mean of x    mean of y 
0.6353091867 0.0006874317
```

Which leads me to reject the null in favor of the alternative. The difference in means is different to 0: The sample in before_time is more likely to be affected by condition `1`.

Note that this is the whole actual population divided into two groups. An alternative option would  be to actually sample of equal size from both sets, and do a `t.test` for the sample, but this seems like a wrong approach given the fact that I have the actual population at time X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a test of binomial proportions. You have some number of elements in each group, $n_1, n_2$, and a certain number of those elements are what you could call "successes" in a Bernoulli trial, i.e. $x_{1_i} = 1$. The sum of all these successes is some number $y_1 = \sum x_{1_i}$. So really all you are doing is testing two binomial proportions $\frac{y_1}{n_1}, \frac{y_2}{n_2}$. There are several ways to do this, but based on your large sample size, the normal approximation should be just fine (assuming the $x$ are independent Bernoulli trials). Look at the `prop.test` function in R.

Just be aware that with your large sample sizes you are pretty much guaranteed to get a p-value less than the classic 0.05 (unless the numbers are nearly identical). You may want to think about what is a practically significant difference rather than settling for simple statistical significance.

Comment: The problem for `prop.test` is that it requires the same length for trials. Which in this case is not true. How could I correct for this?

Comment: I think you may have misread the help file for `prop.test`. There is no requirement for equal length trials. You simply need to provide a vector of the success and a vector of the trials. For example: `prop.test(x = c(100, 200), n = c(200, 300))`